# How to attach DataTable() to existing HTML <table> with the data in array (v-for loop) using Vue.js?

Tags: jquery, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, datatable

I have a problem in Vue.js and cannot make my table to be DataTable (with search field, sort columns, etc.).

I call the original `datatable.min.js` inside `<head>` and either have and call another `custom.js` file which has got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#zero_configuration_table").DataTable()
});
```

How can I call and/or attach like in jQuery  `$('#zero_configuration_table').DataTable();`?.

I do not know wher should I put that code to get it working.

I cannot apply example from this https://codepen.io/feload/pen/PJKoJP?editors=1010. Even from https://datatables.net/.

In my .vue file for the call it "Table page" I have:

```
<template>
...
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="zero_configuration_table" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
<caption>Popis pristiglih prijava korisnika aplikacije</caption>
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
<th scope="col">DATUM I VRIJEME</th>
<th scope="col">OSOBA</th>
<th scope="col">SADRŽAJ PORUKE</th>
<th scope="col">KONTAKT INFORMACIJE</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr v-for="ci in chatItems">
<td class="align-middle"><strong>{{ci.datumPoruka | formatDate}}</strong> u <strong>{{ci.datumPoruka| formatDateVrijeme}}</strong></td>
<td class="align-middle"><a :href="ci.fotografijaKorisnik" title="Pogledaj uvećanu fotografiju korisnika" target="_blank"><img :src="ci.fotografijaKorisnik" :alt="'Fotografija korisnika '+ci.imeKorisnik" width="40" height="40" class="okrugla"></a> {{ci.imeKorisnik}}</td>
<td v-if="ci.sadrzajPoruka.length && !ci.datotekaPoruka.length && !ci.kartaLat.length" class="align-middle">{{ci.sadrzajPoruka}}</td>
<td v-else-if="!ci.sadrzajPoruka.length && ci.datotekaPoruka.length && !ci.kartaLat.length" class="align-middle"><a :href="ci.datotekaPorukaURL" target="_blank" title="Pogledaj uvećanu fotografiju" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Pogledaj uvećanu fotografiju <em class="fa fa-external-link"></em></a></td>
<td v-else-if="!ci.sadrzajPoruka.length && !ci.datotekaPoruka.length && ci.kartaLat.length" class="align-middle"><a :href="'https://www.google.com/maps/place/'+ci.kartaLat+','+ci.kartaLong" target="_blank" title="Pogledaj na karti" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Pogledaj na karti <em class="fa fa-external-link"></em></a></td>
<td v-else class="align-middle">Prazna poruka</td>
<td class="align-middle"><a :href="'mailto:'+ci.emailKorisnik" title="Pošalji e-mail"><em class="fa fa-envelope"></em>&nbsp;{{ci.emailKorisnik}}</a><br><em class="fa fa-phone"></em>&nbsp;{{ci.telefonKorisnik}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
...
</template>
```

On export default, under data() I have array of the data:

```
data() {
    return {
         chatItems: []
    }
},
```

Under created the code from FireBase to fetch the specific data and later on in the `<template>` to show the data with `v-for`:

```
created: function(){
    $('#scroll_horizontal_table').DataTable(); // THIS IS THE PROBLEM, HOW AND WHERE TO PUT?

    this.userData(),
    db.ref("chatmodel")
    .once("value")
    .then(dataSnapshot => {
      const itemsArray = [];
      dataSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        const childData = childSnapshot.val();
        itemsArray.push({
          fotografijaKorisnik: childData.userModel.photo_profile,
          imeKorisnik: childData.userModel.name,
          telefonKorisnik: childData.userModel.phoneNumber,
          emailKorisnik: childData.userModel.email,
          datumPoruka: childData.timeStamp,
          sadrzajPoruka: childData.message,
          datotekaPoruka: childData.fileModel.name_file,
          datotekaPorukaURL: childData.fileModel.url_file,
          kartaLat: childData.mapModel.latitude,
          kartaLong: childData.mapModel.longitude
        });
      });
      this.chatItems = itemsArray; // reverse()
    });
},
...
```

Everything seems to work, no errors for dataTable, but It just do not get rendered as the default table with pagination, serach field, etc. as needed.

I do not know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: And I am using jquery-3.3.1.min.js with Bootstrap

Comment: Needed to wait a bit, so setup the setTimeout(function() { $("#zero_horizontal_table").DataTable(); }, 4000); // wait 4 seconds. And then it renders the pagination, search field, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have had calling the DataTable() early, so the data was not yet fetched from FireBase and did not got rendered.

Under methods, I've had few already, so just made a timeout like:

```
methods: {
    userData:function(){
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var name, email, photoUrl, uid;

        setTimeout(function() { $("#zero_horizontal_table").DataTable(); }, 4000);
         // WAIT FOR 4 SECONDS AND THEN APPLY DATATABLE()

...
```

Now it works. It shows pagination, etc.